# mysqldump skipping some tables while taking a backup

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to take a full dump of my database. While taking a dump, mysqldump skips a few tables, especially those with foreign keys. It's not that every table with foreign keys is skipped. Some specific tables only!

I tried the `-f` switch. It forced it to include a few tables but still two tables are being skipped.

Is this normal? I mean, does this happen? Does my schema has some problems? How can this be solved?

Comment: Ahem.. It was McAfee antivirus that caused mysql to skip some tables..  :-p

Comment: What does McAfee have to do with mysql tables? Everyone knows that McAfee is the incompetent devil incarnate, but I'm curious as to how it'd stop mysqldump from spitting out two specific tables, without killing the entire dump.

Comment: It grew a conscience and is taking pity on the server

Comment: I couldn't find the exact reason but as far as I can remember, it was blocking the "mysqldump" process from reading some resources. I was not the only one - http://www.google.com/search?q=mysqldump+mcafee

Comment: does your mysqldump user have enough rights to access said tables in the schema?

Comment: Maybe you should do your database administration at a time when you can be more focused.  i.e. not while taking a dump.

Comment: For all those who think the bad humor was intentional, let me make this clear - it wasn't. The question was and still is genuine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to @Nikhil's comment on McAfee.  I ran into a situation where McAfee was trying to read (and thus was blocking) the temporary files that MySQL creates when queries move from in memory to temporary.  We had to create a specific rule that prevented McAfee from trying to scan the temporary file so that MySQL wouldn't have issues.  In this situation my educated guess would be that McAfee was doing something similar with the MySQL dump process.